# Is it still true that with python3 in Windows it is impossible to input a single character from the screen without hitting enter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen, user-input

It can be done with termios under Unix, but not under Windows.

I do it easily in perl with TERM::Readkey, or in Windows Batch files.

If an answer has been given here, I have been unable to find it.

I find it hard to believe that python omits such a basic operation available in essentially all other languages.

Comment: You mean like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: [`msvcrt.getch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch) works fine for me.  Python 3.5.2, Windows 10.

Comment: is there a solution for linux / ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above returns a byte, not a character, so it needs to be decoded.

Here is a solution that returns a single character without having to hit Enter. It works in python 3.4, on Windows

```
def getChar():
    import msvcrt 
    return msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')
```