# getkey in AutoKey

Tags: linux, autokey

howto wait for key pressed with autokey?

for AutoKey i found the [wait_for_keypress](https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting.Keyboard-class.html#wait_for_keypress) but its not what i searching for.

its wait for a defined keypress or key combination.

i want wait for <kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>b</kbd>,... <kbd>z</kbd> is pressed.

i searched here:

- https://github.com/autokey/autokey#documentation
- https://autokey.github.io/index.html

and tried soe of this exaples without success:

- [Detecting a keypress in python while in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863921/detecting-a-keypress-in-python-while-in-the-background)
- [Is it still true that with python3 in Windows it is impossible to input a single character from the screen without hitting enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851272/is-it-still-true-that-with-python3-in-windows-it-is-impossible-to-input-a-single)

i seached the web for

- `autokey -autohotkey keywait manual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following solution only works with root rights:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install keyboard
sudo autokey
```

then this works (tested in Kubuntu 20.04, see Details below):

```
import keyboard as keyboard2 # must be different name becouse of name conflicts
while True:
    key = keyboard2.read_key()
    if keyboard2.is_pressed(' '): 
        keyboard.send_keys("You pressed space")
    if key == "p":
        break
```

tested with:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
```

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 i had to set `xhost +` to run autokey with sudo and it still throws `ModuleNotFoundError` on keyboard import